# Anylogic: Source-block - Arrivals defined by stock of queue

Tags: anylogic

I am testing some production simulations in Anylogic.
Is it possible to link the arrival of multiple Agents (in my case: 20 pcs/arrival) to the actual stock of agents in a queue-block?

For example if there are less than 5 pcs of agents in queue then create a new arrival of 20 agents.
At the beginning of the Simulation the source-block should generate 20 agents. But in the course of the simulation the condition for new arrivals should change to the stock condition in the queue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an event for time=0 (or at the Main agent startup) such as `source.inject(20);`. You can have the queue block after this `source`. This would inject 20 agents into the queue. New arrivals can follow the same logic triggered by the conditions.

```
if (yourCondition==true){
     source.inject(20);
}
```